# pg gem install fails, cannot find libpq-fe.h header

Tags: centos, capistrano, bundler, pg, centos7

Whenever I run `bundle install` on my VPS (CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)) I get an error when installing the pg gem.

```
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I can install pg standalone with: `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config` and the issue is resolved.

So I added a capistrano taskto create a ./bundle/config for the deploy with the build.pg key set with the path to pg_config on my VPS. In the Capistrano `config/deploy.rb` this is invoked `before bundler:install`.

```
desc "Create bundle config"
task :prepare_bundle_config do
  on roles(:app) do
    within release_path do
      execute :bundle, 'config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config --local'
    end
  end
end
```

I have the necessary packages installed:

```
postgresql94-server.x86_64
postgresql94-devel.x86_64
postgresql94-libs.x86_64
libpqxx.x86_64
libpqxx-devel.x86_64
```

Here are the capistrano* gems I have installed

```
bundle list | grep capistrano
* capistrano (3.3.5)
* capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
* capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
* capistrano-rbenv (2.0.3)
* capistrano-stats (1.1.1)
```

What am I missing here to successfully install pg with bundler? Please leave a comment if you need any additional information and I will update this post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The postgres binaries are not in the path. Symlink them in to a directory in your path and you should be good: `ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/p* /usr/local/bin`.

Did you build postgres or install it from yum?

Comment: Can your custom task run through Capistrano successfully and independently? What output do you have from Capistrano?

Comment: Thanks for the response: here is a gist with the output from capistrano (with debug) https://gist.github.com/whargrove/03ff94d1b6e7648030ed

Comment: :prepare_bundle_config can't run independently because it uses release_path, so it is only available during the deploy task.

Comment: BTW, symlinking the postgres binaries to the remote user's path seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks! I will reward the bounty as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: worked for me as well, I'm running postgresql 9.3 on CentOS 7, thanks a lot

Comment: @JoePasq you just recovered me out of a 2-day long hair-pulling adventure with one line.  Kudos to you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the solution for PostgreSQL 11. If someone lands here.

```
sudo yum install epel-release

sudo yum install postgresql11-llvmjit

sudo yum install postgresql11-devel postgresql11-libs
```

Then run

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3' -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_config
```

Thats it

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you're using a Mac

```
brew link postgresql
```

Or in my case

```
brew link postgresql@12
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I compile pgsql with source code, and PATH ENV not configed with pgsql/bin, this happends. You can have a try with this.